# Numpy concatenating ints to string

Tags: python, numpy

I have a rather big numpy array of M*N ints and I want to end up with a M array of strings that have all N corresponding ints concatenated.
I tried using a view but this is probably not the way to go with numpy.

Comment: Please shows some example input and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you want

```
numpy.apply_along_axis(numpy.array_str,0,array)
```

Look the documentation of apply_along_axis

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html

and array_str

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_str.html

for deeper understanding

Comment: The output of this looks fishy: `np.apply_along_axis(np.array_str,1,np.arange(12).reshape(3,4))` => `array(['[0 1 2 3]', '[4 5 6 7]', '[ 8  9 10'], dtype='|S9')`

Comment: `np.array([np.array_str(x) for x in X])` handles the variable length of the lines better.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to concatenating `ints` to `string` it wasnt be `numpy` array longer ! you will have a list with string indexes.

this is an example that concatenate 'a' to a `numpy` zero array :

```
>>> np.zeros(10)
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])

>>> [str(i)+'a' for i in np.zeros(10)]
['0.0a', '0.0a', '0.0a', '0.0a', '0.0a', '0.0a', '0.0a', '0.0a', '0.0a', '0.0a']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without an example, your request is unclear.  But here's one way of understanding it

```
In [13]: X=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [14]: np.array([''.join([str(i) for i in x]) for x in X])
Out[14]: 
array(['0123', '4567', '891011'], 
    dtype='|S6')
```

I have a 3x4 array; I convert each element to a string using `str(i)`, and use `join` to concatenate the strings of a row into one longer string.

That's not a very satisfying answer, especially when joining '9' to '10'. Of course it could be refined by elaborating on the 'int' to 'string' formatting (ie. fixed width), maybe adding delimiters in the 'join', etc.

```
In [21]: np.array([','.join(['{:*^8}'.format(i) for i in x]) for x in X])
Out[21]: 
array(['***0****,***1****,***2****,***3****',
       '***4****,***5****,***6****,***7****',
       '***8****,***9****,***10***,***11***'], 
      dtype='|S35')
```

A `view` would only work if what you want is some sort of string to bytes representation, or str to char.